# How to control Android phones from a macOS computer by projecting a cursor onto the Android device?

Tags: remote-control, macos

I used to use Samsung Smart Switch for this purpose, but the feature has been discontinued. Currently, I am using scrcpy to mirror the Android screen on my Mac and control it, or I connect to the Android device using 1keyboard as an external keyboard. However, neither of these methods is ideal because I cannot project the cursor directly onto the Android phone itself, which means I have to operate it by looking at my Mac screen. Additionally, the previous method was faster as it didn't require mirroring the entire screen.

Comment: I'm not getting it. If the end goal still remains: "to control device using Mac/PC",  what difference does it make if the real Android screen shows cursor or not, so long as the cursor of your Mac is accurate enough with scrcpy?

Comment: It's a lot slower to project the screen to the mac. It's much faster to project the cursor to the android. @Firelord